# Bulk Upload Chatter Users' Photo

Tags: chatter, user-management

I have a requirement to upload all users' photo in chatter. Is it possible ? or do I need to upload individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using Chatter REST API by targeting [User Photo](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_resources_users_UserPhotos.htm) 
You may check this questions ([1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5184/chatter-rest-api-user-photo-example), [2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/attaching-image-to-chatter-post-using-chatter-rest-api))  it might help you

Give it a try and update your question with your progress and we'll do our best to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try AppExchange App to achieve your Bulk Photo upload requirement,
Mass Chatter Photo Utility App helps you Bulk upload Chatter Users' Photos within clicks.

You can find it on the AppExchange listing, The below link will redirect you to AppExchange
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ecs4kUAB

Full disclosure, I work at Satrang Technologies, the creator of this amazing AppExchange app.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! If my research is correct, you are employed by Satrang Technologies - the creator of the app you linked to. From a section of the SFSE Help Center (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion): *"Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, **you must disclose your affiliation in your answers**."* (emphasis added). Please edit your answer to disclose any affiliation, and please spend some time getting a feel of the culture and expectations of a site you are new to.